# "I want this so bad I'll do anything for it!"

Tags: expressions

When someone says this, we know he obviously doesn't mean he'll "do anything". In this case, what kind of statement is this? It isn't a literal statement too, right?

Comment: It's *hyperbole*, a kind of *exaggeration* (specifically, a ludicrous *overexaggeration*).

Comment: And a grammar mistake starting this type of sentence with I'm instead of I. Want is not continuous. Usually hyperbole, but i'd kill for a klondike bar.

Comment: Not correct: I'm want. Correct: I want. After a form of to be can't follow a bare infinitive.

Comment: huh, and I thought this was gonna be a "bad vs badly" question

Comment: Who are you to make that call? Maybe the person is indeed willing to do anything.. Next time someone approaches you with that question, ask them for a kidney, or to jump-skip every step at work for a week, or sow wings onto their pyjamas and send you a picture... people might just surprise you, and even if most people say no, it'll be worth it for the couple that say yes :D

Answer (score 3):

This is called a [**hyperbole**](http://literarydevices.net/hyperbole/).

> It is a figure of speech, which involves an exaggeration of ideas for the sake of emphasis.

It's when you make a statement that is a clear exaggeration on the reality of the situation. Hyperbole is such a common feature of everyday speech that it usually goes by unnoticed.

These are hyperboles:

1. "I'll kill him if he does that again."
2. "I fell on the floor with laughter."
3. "This is driving me insane."

These are what they actually mean:

1. "I will be very angry with him if he does that again."
2. "I laughed uncontrollably."
3. "This is annoying me."

Comment: Okay, @NVZ . What is confusing you? Then I can edit my answer to make it clearer, if necessary.

Comment: It might be my poor formatting. I should learn some commands and edit, perhaps.

Comment: Thanks, @NVZ... Can you also make my lists fall on single-space lines, rather than having paragraph spacing? Is there a line-break command, for example? Cheeky to ask, I know...

Comment: Excellent, @NVZ. You're making me look very good! I gather you used the built in list function for that part? I had hoped to keep my own numbering format, however, the trade-off is worth it as this looks much better. Thanks a lot.